# How to create a mirror image of a CSS cubic-bezier()

Tags: css, cubic-bezier

I want to create two bezier curves using CSS, the second being a horizontal mirror image of the first.  If both y values are 0.5 and the two x values are the same, I can do it by changing the x values to 1 - x. But if the x values are different that does not work, and it doesn't work with the y values.  I have tried swapping the two points, i.e. setting x1/y1 to x2/y2 and vice-versa, and that isn't even close.

Here is a crude visual of what I want to achieve, using the curve of the built-in easing function named `ease`, e.g. `cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)`:
[image: mirrored bezier]

Now that second curve has P0 and P3 swapped, so it might be a bit confusing, since it starts at 1,1 and ends at 0,0.  I handle that with a `1 - value` calculation. I'm not sure how to visualize it without that, so hopefully you'll understand what I am trying to do...

The idea is to do a round-trip animation where the return trip mirrors the original in its timing.

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/advanced-css-animation-using-cubic-bezier/ (you probably need the parabolic curve there)

Comment: also this: https://css-tricks.com/build-complex-css-transitions-using-custom-properties-and-cubic-bezier/

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Thanks for the links.  fyi - the codepen animations in the 2nd link don't work properly in Firefox.  They work in Chrome though, so I can see the visuals there.  Unfortunately all of the mirror-like examples, like the parabolic curve, have symmetrical coordinates: identical y values, x values that mirror around 0.5, things like that.  It's when x1, y1, x2, and y2 are not aligned that I have the real issue.  But I found the answer in a codepen and answered my own question just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After repeatedly adjusting my web search terms, I found a working answer here:

https://codepen.io/michellebarker/pen/jQpwKq

After fiddling with that codepen, it becomes clear that the answer lies in combining my original approaches:

```
x1 = 1 - x2
y1 = 1 - y2
x2 = 1 - x1
y2 = 1 - y1
```

Comment: If you have solved it, you should go ahead and mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @NkemdiAnyiam - The system forces me to wait two days to do that.  I figured it out too quickly :)